# preg_match_all returns only one match

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I need a pattern for php preg_match_all function to return matches that are inside double curly braces and are between '<body>' and '</body>' strings.

I tried to create such a pattern but it returned only one match. I expected it to return 'Monday' and 'Tuesday' but it returned only 'Tuesday'.

Here is the pattern

```
/<body>(.)*{{(?<DAY>.*?)}}(.)*<\/body>/s
```

Here is the string for testing:

```
<body>
s{s ds
ds{{Monday}}ds
s
dsd}{s
ds{{Tuesday}}dsd sdsd
d{}sd}s


}
{
fdsa dsafasd
</body>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it's only returning one match is because you're matching from the start of the `<body>` element to the closing of the `</body>` element with only a single capturing group.

To work around this, you can use the [`\G` anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/continue.html) in order to continue matching at the end of the previous match:

```
/<body>|(?!^)\G(.*?){{(?<DAY>.*?)}}(?=.*<\/body>)/s
```

[**Live Example**](http://ideone.com/7yPM0m):

```
preg_match_all("/<body>|(?!^)\G(.*?){{(?<DAY>.*?)}}(?=.*<\/body>)/s", $input, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);

foreach ($matches as $match) {
    if (isset($match['DAY'])) {
        echo $match['DAY'];
    }
}
```

Output based on the input you provided:

> Monday Tuesday

---

It's worth pointing out that *if* you know that each of those matches are inside of the `<body>` element, you could simply just use:

```
preg_match_all("/{{(?<DAY>.*?)}}/", $input, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
```

Comment: No, the matches would be between body tags and outside the body. Eg. in head section of the web page code. Thanks for working pattern. One question about this part: "(?!^)". Does it mean anything not followed by the beginning of test string?

Comment: @trzczy The `\G` anchor will continue matching at the end of the previous match **or** it will match starting at the beginning of the string. The negative lookahead `(?!^)` just prevents it from matching at the beginning so that the match always starts with `<body>` and `\G` always continues from there. It appears to work in [this example](http://ideone.com/7yPM0m) if there are matches inside of the `<head>` element.

Comment: Josh, thank you very very very much for the great help!

Answer (score 0):

I think the easier way is to get the text between the body tags in the first step. And with a second regex you get retrive the elements in curly braces

```
/({{(Monday|Tuesday)}})+/s
```